# {"error":"invalid_client","message":"Client authentication failed"}

Tags: oauth-2.0, actions-on-google

[image]
[image]

I completed these steps

- Installed laravel/passport.
- Created a website user.
- Generated passport keys PHP artisan passport: install
- Generated client_id and client_secret using PHP artisan passport:client
- Added redirection and callback routes in web.php
- Authorized the user and got the final access token.

  client information step in the action console. find my application in the home app but when I log in to the web page show client authentication failed.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Unfortunately, you haven't really given us much information to help you. Can you update your question to include screen shots of how you have it configured (masking sensitive information) and the error message you're getting?

Comment: I run the google smart home app on  mobile  there when I log in gets the error above I to mention

Comment: Please review again sir

Comment: I did auth through passport laravel in my web app

Answer (score 3):

The link you provide for the "redirect" URI must be the one that Google has specified. You're redirecting to Google's servers with the information - not your own server.

This URI should be in the form

```
https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/YOUR_PROJECT_ID
```

where `YOUR_PROJECT_ID` is replaced with the project ID for your Action.

Comment: Great! If an answer has helped, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.